# java html font size

Tags: java, html, templates, font-size

I am trying to generate a html file from start with template. I have a problem about the font size as I cannot configure it with the code I provide.

`buildhtml.append("<p style=" + "font-size:" + fontsize * 0.1 + " align=" + "center" + ">F</p>");`

It moves the letter F to the center, but no difference at fontsize.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need semicolons between each property. For the code you gave, that would probably be `buildhtml.append("<p style=\"" + "font-size:" + fontsize * 0.1 + "; align=" + "center\"" + ">F</p>");`.

EDIT: 
You also need to surround the style element with quotes.

Comment: Tried copy paste the code, did not work. Also tried moving quotes to several places, also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found a fix, the missing "%" was the problem:

```
buildhtml.append("<p style=\"" + "font-size: " + (K*0.1) + "%\" align=" + "\"center\"" + ">F</p>");
```